# Date Picker not showing properly. I think something is interfering with it

Tags: php

Something is wrong with my date picker or something interfere's with the code. I think something is interfering with it because I used this datepicker code from my other sample. Whenever I click the textbox the datepicker does not show up.

Sample Picture.

[image: Sample Picture]

This is my code.

```
<?php include('session.php'); ?>
<?php include('header.php'); ?>
<body>
<?php include('navbar.php'); ?>
<div class="container">
<div style="height:50px;"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">     <center>
            <h1 class="page-header">Product Sales Report</h1></center>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <center>
 <form action="total_sales.php" method="post">
  From: <input type="text" class="datepicker" placeholder="E.G.(2018-01-14)" name="dayfrom" required pattern="[0-9]{4}+[0-9]+[0-9]"> To: <input type="text" class="datepicker" placeholder="E.G.(2018-02-11)" name="dayto" required pattern="[0-9]{4}+[0-9]+[0-9]">
  <input type="submit" value="Show Sales" name="salesbtn" ></form></center>

            <table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="prodTable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="hidden"></th>
                        <th>Purchase Date</th>
                        <th>Customer</th>
                        <th>Product Name</th>
                        <th>Quantity</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <?php
                    $sq=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from sales_detail left join product on product.productid=sales_detail.productid left join sales on sales.salesid=sales_detail.salesid left join customer on sales.userid=customer.userid where product.supplierid='".$_SESSION['id']."' order by sales.sales_date desc");;
                    while($sqrow=mysqli_fetch_array($sq)){

                    ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="hidden"></td>
                            <td><?php echo date('M d, Y h:i A',strtotime($sqrow['sales_date'])); ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $sqrow['customer_name']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $sqrow['product_name']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $sqrow['sales_qty']; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php
                    }
                ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php include('script.php'); ?>
<?php include('modal.php'); ?>
<?php include('add_modal.php'); ?>
<script src="custom.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my script.
Is my code lacking in the datepicker script? Help please

```
<script src="../vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../dist/js/sb-admin-2.js"></script>

<!-- DataTables JavaScript -->
<script src="../vendor/datatables/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="../vendor/datatables-plugins/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../vendor/datatables-responsive/dataTables.responsive.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dataTables-example').DataTable({
        responsive: true
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Note: Java != JavaScript & I see no Java here, though there is some JavaScript.

Comment: I can't see anything which is Java related in your question, so why did you assign this tag? Furthermore, I fear we can't help you if you don't show the complete code, including the Javascript parts (if it is too long to post here, then make a JSFiddle or the like, and link to that in your question).

Comment: Can you please share the error in console?

Comment: Do you actually include datepicker's Javascript somewhere? How do you implement it?

Comment: @kerbholz what I did was copy the php script of the datepicker from my older system then just paste it , to my new php. I think it's interfering with some of my css.

Comment: @RajeshYadav there are no error in the console , somehow the calendar does not show up.

Comment: @Gretchen please include datepicker js file in script.js

Answer (score 1):

Use datepicker js file in script.js

Html code

```
<input type="text" id="from_date">
```

Javascript

```
$(function(){
    $( "#from_date" ).datepicker();        
});
```

Or you can use this

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: added it to my history.php file , still nothing happens.